# How to include header file in source distribution?

Tags: python, c, pip, setuptools, cffi

I am trying to create a source distribution containing a simple c function. Here are the files I have.

```
# file setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="example",
    version="0.1",
    py_modules=["example", "build"], # If i dont include build.py, it will not find it.
    cffi_modules=["build.py:ffibuilder"],
    install_requires=["cffi"],
    setup_requires=["cffi"],
)
```

```
# file "build.py"

from cffi import FFI

ffibuilder = FFI()

SOURCE = """
#include "factorial.h"
"""

ffibuilder.cdef(
    """
long long int factorial(int n);
"""
)

ffibuilder.set_source(
    module_name="_example",
    source=SOURCE,
    sources=["factorial.c"],
    include_dirs=["."],
    library_dirs=["."],
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ffibuilder.compile(verbose=True)
```

```
// file "factorial.c"
#include "factorial.h"

long long int factorial(int n)
{
    long long int result = 1;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        result *= i;
    return result;
}
```

```
// file "factorial.h"
long long int factorial(int n);
```

With these files I run the command

```
python setup.py sdist
```

Which generates the file "dist\example-0.1.tar.gz". And when I try to install it using

```
pip install example-0.1.tar.gz
```

I get

```
build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\_example.c(570): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'factorial.h': No such file or directory
```

So how do I include the header file in the source distribtuion?

Comment: Found a solution. In the setup.py file add the following line"package_data={"": ["*.h"]}" this will include all the header files in the directory.

Comment: If you have a solution, you have two choices: 1) Delete your question, if you think that it has little or no value for others. 2) Post an own answer and mark it (later, when allowed). -- Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. This is not a forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `package_data`, you could also use a `MANIFEST.in` file as per [4. Building C and C++ Extensions](https://docs.python.org/3.11/extending/building.html).

> In some cases, additional files need to be included in a source distribution; this is done through a `MANIFEST.in` file; see [Specifying the files to distribute](https://docs.python.org/3.11/distutils/sourcedist.html#manifest) for details.

For example, in [numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7776bc6166915322bc61c4be988fc99727bc2f9a/MANIFEST.in#L27-L28) and [pytorch](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/MANIFEST.in), in their `MANIFEST.in`, they include all files in specified folders, **which includes header files**.

Answer (score 1):

Add in the file setup.py, inside the setup function package_data={"": ["*.h"]}. This will include all the header files in the source distribution.

```
setup(
    name="example",
    version="0.1",
    py_modules=["example", "build"], # If i dont include build.py, it will not find it.
    cffi_modules=["build.py:ffibuilder"],
    install_requires=["cffi"],
    setup_requires=["cffi"],
    package_data={"": ["*.h"]} # <- This line
)
```